# Observable and Angular2

Tags: json, angular, observable

I have an issue with Observables in Angular 2

My component calls service function on Init like below:

```
delivery: IDeliveryCountry[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.checkoutService._getInfo().subscribe(dev => this.delivery = dev); 
}
```

This is how interface looks like IDeliveryCountry:

```
export interface IDeliveryCountry {
  iso: string;
  name: string;
}
```

This is how Service looks like:

```
_getInfo(): Observable<IDeliveryCountry[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.deliveryCountryUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => <IDeliveryCountry[]>response.json()) 
}
```

json file with data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "iso":"se",
    "name":"Sweden"
  },
  {
    "iso":"dk",
    "name":"Denmark"
  }
]
```

My html file is just a simple ngFor loop:

```
<div *ngFor='let dev of delivery'>{{dev.iso}}</div>
```

So far all things works perfect, as expected I get back "se" and "dk" in UI.

The problem appears when I change a structure of data in my json file to following:

```
{
  "country": {
    "iso":"se",
    "name":"Sweden"
  }
}
```

I want data to only have one country with iso and name property for it. So my html file looks like following:

```
<div>{{delivery.iso}}</div>
```

But I am getting iso as undefined all the time

> " Cannot read property 'iso' of undefined "

Thank you!

Comment: *The problem appears when I change a structure of data in my json file to following:* ... where do you change it? backend? If so, then what data are you actually receiving? and what have you assigned to `delivery` when you are trying to print `delivery.iso`. Is it just the `{
  "country":{
      "iso":"se",
      "name":"Sweden"
  }
}` Your question is a bit unclear, at least for me :D

Comment: I change it in my API so that returns

{
  "country":{
      "iso":"se",
      "name":"Sweden"
  }
}

Instead of 
[
{
  "iso":"se",
  "name":"Sweden"
},
{
  "iso":"dk",
  "name":"Denmark"
}
]

Answer (score 1):

You should first of all use:

```
{{delivery.country.iso}}
```

The undefined error you are getting, is because the data is coming async, so use the [**safe navigation operator**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) to avoid this:

```
{{delivery?.country?.iso}}
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VRyL4A2ab8JQvDTGafx5?p=preview)

Optionally you could extract the data that is inside `country`, so you can shorten your code in your template from `{{delivery?.country?.iso}}` to just `{{delivery?.iso}}`, this can be done like so:

```
.map(res => res.json().country) // extract the data from the object country
```

Comment: is not the same thing i have answer?

Comment: I don't see the safe navigation operator there?

Comment: it was there in the comment

Comment: Thx a lot!!! You are right i just saw that :) safe navigation operation make it work. Thx to both of you!!!

Comment: @Sajeetharan well I didn't look at comments, just the answer (which then didn't have the safe navigation operator), and I think that the comment might not even have been there when I started writing my answer... Of course I wouldn't have posted a duplicate answer, I'm not that crazy ;)

Comment: It's ok, i was wondering is there anything different from what i have posted! cheers!

Comment: @Sajeetharan... well *NOW* there isn't any difference anymore, after your edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this without ngFor since it is an Object

```
<div>{{delivery.country.iso}}</div>
```

After your comments, undefined is because the data is coming async, so use the elvis operator to avoid this:

```
 {{delivery?.country?.iso}}
```

Comment: Nope I tried that too but I get "Cannot read property 'country' of undefined" I also changed declaration of delivery from   delivery: IDeliveryCountry[]; to   delivery: IDeliveryCountry; same for Observable too:

_getInfo(): Observable<IDeliveryCountry> {
        return this.http.get(this.deliveryCountryUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <IDeliveryCountry> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

Comment: this is how data looks in console when i have .do in Observable {"country":{"iso":"se","name":"Sweden"}}

Comment: It should get printed, can you try this {{delivery?.country?.iso}}

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could change your service to return the DeliveryCountry[]

```
getInfo(): Observable<IDeliveryCountry[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.deliveryCountryUrl)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json()) 
  .map(delivery => delivery.country);
}
```

Then:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.checkoutService.getInfo()
  .subscribe(deliveryCountries => this.deliveryCountries = deliveryCountries);
}
```

Then:

```
<div *ngFor="let deliveryCountry of deliveryCountries">{{deliveryCountry?.iso}}</div>
```